# Publish embed video in Facebook Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm trying to publish a video using the PHP SDK. Use the method 'feed' and and then I show the code you i'm using. I using a flv video.

```
$response = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'POST', array(
                'message' => 'My custom message',
                'name' => 'Whatever name',
                'description' => 'Whatever description',
                'link' => 'http://localhost/my_proyect/',
                'picture' => 'http://localhost/my_proyect/my_image.png',
                'source' => 'http://localhost/my_proyect/videos/my_video.flv',
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Some Actions',
                        'link' => 'http://localhost/my_proyect/'
                    )
                ),
                'caption' => 'Cool Video'
                    ));
echo json_encode($response);
```

In my HTML i put the FB meta tags.

```
<!-- FB Meta Tags -->
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost/my_proyect/" />
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://localhost/my_proyect/videos/my_video.flv" />
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        <!-- FB Meta Tags END -->
```

When I see the response. Return a array with the ID of post.

When I see the user's wall, just see the post with the text but not the embedded video or image.

What is it I'm doing wrong in my code? Do I need to pass a player or the player that plays my video is by default? Or do not work because I'm on my localhost?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the `message`

Comment: @AviramSegal I removed the message and does not work :(

Comment: OK.. I found the solution.. I delete ACTIONS and it's works